# Pass binary file as JSON parameter using multipart/form-data using curl POST

Tags: json, post, curl, multipartform-data

I've searched  a bunch and can't find the answer the answer to this.

I'm trying to pass a binary file as a JSON parameter using multipart/form-data using curl for a POST request. I tried this, but it doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
curl -X POST http://api.example.com \
-H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
-F "data={\"key\": \"@text.txt\"};type=application/json"
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. It would look like this:

curl -X POST http://api.example.com \
-H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
-F "data={\"key\": \"file1\"};type=application/json" \
-F "file1=@text.txt"